# Matlab , Error while plotting Heaviside. (Vectors must be the same length.)

Tags: matlab

I am doing a problem on Hamming code in Matlab.  I have generated a bit string of length  1190, for transmission. I am asked to display the string as a curve of step function.

After doing some researched i found that the Heaviside function can be used for display the bit string as unit step curve.

When I use the command `fplot(heaviside(l_f),[0 ,10000])`, to plot the curve, where `l_f` is the bit string of length `1190`, I get this error

> Error using fcnchk (line 106)
>
> FUN must be a function, a valid string expression, or an inline
>   function object.
>
> Error in fplot (line 60)
>     fun = fcnchk(fun);
>
> Error in Untitled (line 88)
>   fplot(heaviside(l_f),[0 ,10000])

When i  display using Plot, i.e `plot(heaviside(l_f),[0 ,10000])`, I get the error

> Error using plot Vectors must be the same length.
>
> Error in Untitled (line 88) plot(heaviside(l_f),[0 ,10000])

Anyway to plot the bit string as a curve of step function ?

Answer (score 0):

`fplot(heaviside(l_f),[0 ,10000])` won't plot since `fplot` requires a `function` as first parameter. But in here it is a matrix. So use `plot` instead. Next, dimension of `heaviside(l_f)` will be `1x1190` and dimension of [0 ,10000] is `1x2`. So wont work since dimensions are different so use.

```
x=heaviside(l_f)
y=0:(10000+1)/length(l_f):10000;
plot(x,y);
```